# ValueError: Extra data: while loading JSON

Tags: python, json

i have a problem with loading JSON.

```
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read().decode('utf-8')
print ("raw data >> ", data)
data1 = json.loads(data)
print (data1)
```

gives me an error:

```
raw data >>  {"Len":"0000000000000376"}{"PipeType":2,"Content":{"ActionType":1,"Data":{"UserID":12,"RoomID":1,"UserData":{"NickName":"Koko","MoreAboutMe":null,"Age":21,"Man":false,"Area":9,"HaveCam":false,"isOldPoll":false,"LoginTime":635292689335460656,"RoomEnter":635292689335460656,"FacebookId":null,"Email":null,"FirstName":null,"LastName":null,"BirthDate":null,"FacebookLink":null,"Rank":-1}}}}{"Len":"0000000000000159"}{"PipeType":2,"Content":{"ActionType":3,"Data":{"Message":"no matter","ColorID":0,"UserID":13,"UserNick":"Jovani","SentDate":null,"Rank":null}}}
Exception in Tkinter callback
...
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 26 - line 1 column 587 (char 26 - 587)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: That's not JSON. That looks like several JSON strings stuck together.

Answer (score 6):

[`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) does not handle multiple json data.

Following is a workaround for that.

```
import json
import re

nonspace = re.compile(r'\S')
def iterparse(j):
    decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
    pos = 0
    while True:
        matched = nonspace.search(j, pos)
        if not matched:
            break
        pos = matched.start()
        decoded, pos = decoder.raw_decode(j, pos)
        yield decoded

rawdata = '{"Len":"0000000000000376"}{"PipeType":2}'
for decoded in iterparse(rawdata):
    print(decoded)
```

output:

```
{u'Len': u'0000000000000376'}
{u'PipeType': 2}
```

Comment: Great job. Had you already encountered this issue in the past?

Comment: @beroe, Yes, I did. The code come from my previous answer. (I don't remember which one).

Comment: Great. Good answer then as now. Funny how something that is a common problem like this was deemed "off topic" in that instance.

Comment: Thanks, it looks much better

Comment: @user1641071, If you have another question, please post a separated question.